# Disable credential contents from forwarding the mail

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a site in asp .net where super admin registers the members with project_id and email_id. 
Then the super admin can send the feedback link to that customer, the condition is after sending the link the link should only be visible to the particular customer. 
If he forwards that message the receiver should not be able to see the same. If the customer completes the questions in the link he should not be able to see it anymore, and if the answers are incomplete he should be able to use the link another time. 
How do I achieve this?

Comment: Have them create a login with a  password. perhaps use 2-factor authentication as well. Besides, how does anyone actually *know* a person behind a screen and keyboard is who they say they are.

Comment: You can't stop users from sharing/forwarding. Even if you do they can still copy paste/take screenshots/show each other. I see no attempt at any code either, for people to help you with your code you need to display some code, you can even use example code as long as the answer would still fit your program.